# PSQL/Spring Boot type syntax error for new column data that I am trying to add

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

Using Postgres and Spring Boot. Running into the following error when I try to add the following column and data to my table.

```
psql:resorts.sql:51: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type smallint: "https://someurl.com/that-im/trying-to-add/"
LINE 24:     'https://someurl.com/that-im/trying-to-add/'
```

Where I add in the column in my Spring Boot Model the column above is a `short` but I clearly define this column as a `String` as seen here:

```java
  @Column(name = "things")
  private short things;

  @Column(name = "item_url")
  private String itemUrl;
```

My sql file where I insert the data into the database looks like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (
    ...,
    things,
    item_url
) VALUES (
    ...,
    5,
    'https://someurl.com/that-im/trying-to-add/'
),(
```

When I remove the column for `item_url` and remove it and the url from the SQL file everything works, but as soon as I put them back in I get the error above. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: whatever is making the mapping from your entity to the sql command is clearly missing fields. By the error it looks it is mapping on the generated insert command the url string to the position of the short (smallint) field

Comment: So enable the SQL logs in your SB app and check the generated SQL

Comment: @JorgeCampos I appreciate the help, but unfortunately I don't know how to do that. I just learned Spring Boot and SQL 2 weeks ago so I'm not completely familiar with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up being the case was that when the table in my database was initially created I had accidentally labeled the type for the `item_url` as a short. Despite changing it in the SB model file to a String it still wouldn't take on the table.

From there I attempted to `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` which deleted my table but for some reason would not allow to re-create a table with the old name. So I went into the SB model file and SQL seeder file and changed the name of the table to something else. From there it was able to create a a new table with all of the correct data and types with no errors.